# Trying to call a second table view with the items of de selected playlist in the first view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

Maybe there's someone outthere who can help me fiure out my problem. I cant seem to display the playlistItems using cocoalibspotify. I have set up my playlistview and the first ableviewcontroller shows the playlist but when i try to call the items of the selected playlist I seem to get 0 numbersof row as my outputs show. the first view show how i pass the indexpath to the secondviewcontroller. the second script show my .h and .m files of the playlistitemsTavle view controller.

Overview.m - tableView with Playlists

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [playlistView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    playlistItemViewController *trailsController = [[playlistItemViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    trailsController.currentPlaylist = [playlistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[[self navigationController] pushViewController:trailsController animated:YES];
    [self getSongs];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPlaylistItem"]) {
        UITableViewCell *BasicCell = (UITableViewCell *) sender;
        NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:BasicCell];
        SPPlaylist *selectedPlaylist = [playlistArray objectAtIndex:ip.row];

        playlistItemViewController *pivc = (playlistItemViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        pivc.currentPlaylist = selectedPlaylist;
    }
}
```

playlistitemsViewController.h -

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "CocoaLibSpotify.h"
    #import "Simple_PlayerAppDelegate.h"
    #import "overViewController.h"


    @interface playlistItemViewController : UITableViewController

    {
        UITableView *tableView;
    }

    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

    @property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) SPPlaylist *currentPlaylist;




    @end
```

playlistViewController.m - this should call the playlist items

```
#import "playlistItemViewController.h"


@interface playlistItemViewController ()

@end


@implementation playlistItemViewController {

}

@synthesize currentPlaylist;
@synthesize tableView;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection: %d",[[currentPlaylist items] count]);
    return [[currentPlaylist items] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SubtitleCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[currentPlaylist items] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;


    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SubtitleCell"];
        [[cell.backgroundView  superview] bringSubviewToFront:cell.backgroundView];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    }
    else{
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"SubtitleCell"];
        }
        SPPlaylistItem * item = [[currentPlaylist items] objectAtIndex:[[currentPlaylist items]count] - indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [item.item name];

        if (item.itemClass == [SPTrack class]) {
            SPTrack * track = item.item;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [track consolidatedArtists];
        }

    }
    return cell;


}


@end
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to by implementing both didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue. In each of those methods you're creating or referencing a playlistItemViewController. If you've made your controller in the storyboard, and are using segues, then you don't need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: if have removed the didselectrow method because i'm indeed using prepare for segue...but i'am still getting 0 playist items

Comment: Where are you getting 0 playlist items? If you log selectedPlaylist in PrepareForSegue, what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the playlist to load before the items are available.

Your playlist view controller needs to use `SPAsyncLoading` to load the playlist, something list this:

```
[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:self.currentPlaylist timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedItems, NSArray *notloadedItems) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Playlist loading can take a while, so make sure you put up some "loading" UI. You'll also need to load the visible tracks in a similar manner before their names will be available.

Comment: I've managed to solve it. There was indeed something wrong with the prepare for segue method. So i changed that and than I added the code above in my playlist view ande guess what...IT WORKED...thanks guys....so again thank you so much for your help....